# Why did natives use 'a' over 'the' in the 2 following cases?

Tags: articles

Recently I asked [a question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225488/is-it-correct-to-use-the-with-person-the-very-first-time-in-the-sentence/225502) about articles. Since I did not understand that case clearly I continued on this topic and have a couple of another questions why authors (native English speakers) used 'a' over 'the'.

1. A person says:

> Next summer, I'll be on a island, with your girlfriend, and **a** pocket full of numbers.

Why did he say '**a** pocket' if it's obvious he was talking about his pocket?

2. Another person says:

> I'm riding with **a** friend that is high as me

Why did he say '**a** friend' if the situation occurred in the car in which there were nobody except them 2.

P.S. Actually, the words 'girlfriend' and 'friend' were replaced over strong language.

Comment: An island, not 'a island'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two types of articles - *definite* (*the*) and *indefinite* (*a/an*).  There's also not using an article, sometimes called the *zero article*.

What does it mean for X definite or indefinite?  *Definite* in this case simply means:

- "which X" matters,
- the speaker/writer expects the listener/reader to know which X if asked.

Indefinite means:

- "which X" does not matter

Because this depends on a common understanding between speaker/writer and listener/reader, or an *assumed* understanding, you often can't tell  whether something is definite or not merely from the words in the sentence.

---

> Next summer, I'll be on an island, with your girlfriend, and a pocket full of numbers.

You don't need to care which island the speaker/writer will be on, or which pocket the numbers are in.

> > Next summer, I'll be on *the* island, with your girlfriend, and a pocket full of numbers.

Speaker/writer expects you to know which island.  If you didn't actually know, you'd have to ask and give away your ignorance.

> I'm riding with a friend that is high as me

You don't need to care which friend is riding with the speaker/writer.  This may be because the speaker/writer doesn't want to tell you or believes you don't know his/her friend.

Answer (score 0):

Because the words “pocket” and “friend” are *just introduced* — they were not already used before.

It doesn't matter that we may precisely determine *which* pocket/friend it is, the only important thing is that they are just introduced, and they are not names of unique objects (as e.g. the *Earth*).

“I have **an** apple. **The** apple is red.” (After introducing an object, we use “the”.)

Comment: 1. Could you please take a look at the linked question and say whether the rule *just introduced* works there?
2. If i would go with 'the pocket' and 'the friend', would I be mistaken?

Comment: 1. It isn't about the “just introduced” rule, it's about uniqueness (as the Earth). 2. Definitely yes, it would be incorrect.

Comment: one more question please if you don't mind. *I got **a/the** jacket that nobody has got in my city.* Which one the or a?

Comment: Definitely “... **a** jacket...”.

Answer (score 0):

Besides MarianD's remarks: *a pocket full of numbers* may suggest a measurement – a *pocketful*, a collection of numbers (women's telephone numbers?) that suffices to fill up a pocket – rather than the contents of a literal pocket.